# Compact enumerations with dynamical label widths

Tags: enumitem

I changed the enumerate environment to be a bit more compact, but now the indentation of the item changes depending on the width of the label:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{align=left,nosep,noitemsep,left=0pt} % Make lists compact
\begin{document}
    Currently:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item abc
        \item abc
        \setcounter{enumi}{10}
        \item abc
        \item abc
        \setcounter{enumi}{100}
        \item abc
        \item abc
    \end{enumerate}

    Wanted:
    \begin{enumerate}[widest=999]
        \item abc
        \item abc
        \setcounter{enumi}{10}
        \item abc
        \item abc
        \setcounter{enumi}{100}
        \item abc
        \item abc
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**By setting `widest`, one can change this behavior. However, I would like this to happen automatically, i.e. depending on the widest label in a list.**

[image: example]

Comment: If you know which is widest, you can set the width ahad of time `\settowidth{\labelwidth}{102. }`  Otherwise you could use the aux file and two runs.

Comment: But I suppose this sets the `labelwidth` for all lists to be the same, no?

Comment: Actually, you would have to create a modified enumerate to reset `\labelwidth`.  With `enumitem` you could use `\begin{enumerate}[widest=102.]`

Comment: If you have enough of these lists to be worth automating, you have enough for the inconsistency in formatting to be problematic. If you have different kinds of enumerated environments, that's different, but it's going to look sloppy and distract from the content if you have multiple almost-similar lists which just differ a bit in the label size. Just pick the largest label you need and set the width globally to that value e.g. `999` or, if you won't go beyond 199, `199`. The position the text starts is one hint to the reader about the level, for example, if you nest them.